# Antd Select console error: `children` should be `Select.Option` or `Select.OptGroup` instead of `Option`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, antd

I am using a wrapper around Antd Select component.

```
import { Select as ASelect } from 'antd';

function Select({ children, ...props }) {
  return <ASelect {...props}>{children}</ASelect>;
}

function Option({ children, ...props }) {
  return <ASelect.Option {...props}>{children}</ASelect.Option>;
}

Select.Option = Option;
```

Which is throwing the below error where ever this component is used.

```
Warning: `children` should be `Select.Option` or `Select.OptGroup` instead of `Option`.
```

Usage:

```
<Select defaultValue="option1" style={{ width: 120 }}>
  {options.map((o) => {
    const { key, label } = o;

    return (
      <Select.Option key={key} value={key}>
        {label}
      </Select.Option>
    );
  })}
</Select>
```

Options Array:

```
const options = [
  { key: 'option1', label: 'Option 1' },
  { key: 'option2', label: 'Option 2' },
  { key: 'option3', label: 'Option 3' },
];
```

Live [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-uixg1y-11xybd?devToolsHeight=33&file=demo.tsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the latest version of Antd ([5.0.0](https://ant.design/components/select)) you can simply pass `options` as a prop.

```
<Select options={options} defaultValue="option1" style={{ width: 120 }} />
```

Options should now contain `value` instead of `key`. ( unique key for every option will be handled by Select component internally )

```
const options = [
  { value: 'option1', label: 'Option 1' },
  { value: 'option2', label: 'Option 2' },
  { value: 'option3', label: 'Option 3' },
];
```

`children` is optional now.

You need to update your base Select implementation as below else you will end up with No Data in the select. ( As you might not use `children` in every `Select` instance )

```
function Select(props) {
  return <ASelect {...props} />;
}
```

Note: `options` prop is given more priority over children

Working [Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-uixg1y-mtaxxm?devToolsHeight=33&file=demo.tsx) (No console warning)